# Sorting out {encodings}, {font-encodings}, {fontenc}, and {inputenc}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

At the moment, there are four tags that deal with encoding issues: the general [encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encodings) (95 questions), the more specific [font-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-encodings) (57 questions), and the two package-specific tags [fontenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fontenc) (66 questions) and [inputenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inputenc) (64 questions). The assignment of tags to specific questions seems to be at least partially a matter of chance: [encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encodings) questions will usually be about either font or input encoding, and [font-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-encodings) questions will sometimes specifically deal with the `fontenc` package.

I suggest that two tags are enough. Let's make [fontenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fontenc) a synonym of [font-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-encodings). Let's create a new [input-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input-encodings) tag and make the existing [inputenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inputenc) tag a synonym of it. The questions tagged with [encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encodings) should be manually retagged to either [font-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-encodings) or [input-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input-encodings); some questions will feature both of these tags.

Comment: Fully agree. And well done for spotting the issue!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As my proposal has so far gained a score of +9, I've changed/added the tag wiki excerpts for [font-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-encodings) and the new [input-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input-encodings):

> {input-encodings} is about the various input code pages like latin1 or
>   utf-8 ({unicode}) which interprete the sequence of numbers underlying text
>   files and map each number to a certain glyph (character). A popular
>   package for pdfLaTeX is inputenc.
>
> {font-encodings} is about the various font or output code pages like
>   T1 (for Latin) or T2*x* (for Cyrillic) which tell the compiler where
>   to find a particular glyph (character) in a font file, hereby
>   supporting correct hyphenation of words. A popular package for
>   pdfLaTeX is fontenc.

I ask a moderator to

- make [fontenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fontenc) a synonym of [font-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-encodings) and merge the existing tags/questions;
- make [inputenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inputenc) a synonym of [input-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input-encodings) and merge the existing tags/questions.

Questions tagged with [encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encodings) will be manually retagged in the following weeks.

EDIT: Retagging has been completed; right now, there are 135 [font-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-encodings) and 109 [input-encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input-encodings) questions (with 14 questions featuring both tags).

Comment: I support your approach, but what about new users, who don't know the difference between [tag:font-encodings] and [tag:input-encodings]? I see mistagged posts coming.

Comment: @HenriMenke Sometimes this can't be avoided. At least it shouldn't get as bad as right now with the [tag:align] tag which is often used by mistake (i.e., other than for the `align` environment) instead of the correct [tag:horizontal-alignment].

Answer (score 6):

I agree with you. It isn't meaningful to mix input encoding and font encoding.

However I fear that the [encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encodings) tag may reappear. So I think it would be good to keep [encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encodings) for only those 3 questions which actually deal with both (difference between them, loading order). In addition it should be made clear in the [encodings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encodings) tag wiki, that either input or font encoding should be chosen for a specific issue.

Comment: Regarding your concern: We also didn't keep the [tag:figures] tag just because we feared it might reappear.

Comment: @lockstep Actually we kept {figures}, as a synonym, so it cannot reappear as a normal tag. However, {encoding} would not fit as a synonym, that's why I made this suggestion.

Comment: True. A better example: We killed the [tag:layout] tag; see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/the-layout-tag-is-redundant

Comment: I understand the fear, but I don't believe it should prevent us from removing a bad tag (assuming it's deemed bad). If it reappears, we'll reremove it :)

Comment: [tag:encoding] could be a reasonable tag for a question dealing with string manipulation in Luatex.